# Alternative use of simpson's

Tags: calculus, simpsons-rule

I have been brushing up on my calculus. And Im curious as to wether you can use simpsons to find the time instead of distance. since in a give problem its always the time and list of velocities given. Is it possible to use simpsons to get the Time instead when only a set of differing Speed equally spaced Distance traveled is given?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can do that. In terms of Riemann sums, the time taken to run $\Delta x$ at a rate of $V$ is $\Delta t := \frac{1}{V} \Delta x$. Assuming we have $V$ as a function of $x$ (i.e. we know the velocity at any given point, rather than any given time), then the integral $\int_0^M \frac{1}{V(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x$ will determine the time taken to run from $0$ to $M$. You can then apply Simpson's rule to obtain a reasonable estimate of the integral.

Warning: it is assumed here that the velocity is always positive! Otherwise it will be impossible to express $V$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: Just to make sure, for example a car is running at distances of 10, 20, 30 km, at which point the speed is found out to be 50, 60, 70 km/hr respectively. Using Simpson's would be something like 10/3*(1(1/50)+4(1/60)+1(1/70)= 0.101 hrs.

Comment: I was perturbed by your end result, but I think you must have made a mistake with the calculation. The correct calculation is about [$0.34$ hours](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B10%2C3%5D*%5C%2840%291%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C50%5D%5C%2841%29%2B4%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C60%5D%5C%2841%29%2B1%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C70%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29), or about $20$ minutes and $11$ seconds.

Comment: You're right. My bad. Thank you for taking time on this.